# Copy Huge Table with Transformations into Another Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, bulk-insert

I have a large table that was imported from a CSV using the import wizard.  I have a query that selects from this table and replaces all of the string "code" columns with integer ids from other dimension tables and performs some transformations on some other columns.  This all works well.

I need to insert the results of this query into a table in the database that has the required foreign key links and indices.  This is also the table that the SQL objects (sprocs, functions, views) use to access the data.

My issue is that the insert takes forever (1.2 hrs) before it eventually dies by complaining about the size of the transaction log.  I don't have access to log onto the server.  I only have access through SSMS with db_owner rights on the database in question.

My questions are:

1. How can I perform the insert without logging it in the transaction log?  I know there is `BULK INSERT` and `OPENROWSET(BULK ...)` but these require a file.
2. Would the insert go faster if I drop the indices? I think this would break the execution plan of the existing SQL objects that use the destination table. Is this advisable if there is a clustered index on the destination table?
3. Is not logging the insert the correct way to go or should I use some other method?

Comment: What recovery model is the DB set to: simple or full? (Properties of particular DB -> Options)  What's the Log file max size set to? (Properties of particular DB -> Files)

Comment: Inserting data into the target table in the ORDER of the clustering index could significantly reduce page splits.  Over and above the new data you're inserting, page splits generate a ton of transaction log data and slow the whole process down in general.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Great tip. (+1) However, I cannot use `ORDER BY` in a `VIEW` definition.  I have since saved my transformation SQL as a view and am using the *Import and Export Data* program found in the Start Menu under SQL Server to move the data from the view into the table.  I am having some cleaning issues so this keeps failing at the moment.  Can you add an `ORDER BY` in the *Import and Export Data* program?

Comment: An option would be to create a stored procedure with the select top 100 percent * from your view order by clustered index columns and then use the import/export wizard to consume the output of your stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-time job, you might just use the `BCP Utility` to do this task.

It seems that your hanging point is doing a massive import that exceeds the resources of your disk space.  The thing you need to do is to break the import into **batches**, which `BCP` supports, so as to avoid a transaction that cannot fit into your server.

When I have had to make a single massive data transfer, I have had good success using the `BCP` utility to extract the data to a file.  This does, of course, require a file location to temporarily hold the extracted data.

Use [The BCP Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) examples from MSDN as samples. (Scroll to see entire commands.)

**Copy Data to File Storage:**

```
 bcp WorlWideImporters.Warehouse.StockItemTransactions OUT D:\BCP\StockItemTransactions_native.bcp -m 1 -n -e D:\BCP\Error_out.log -o D:\BCP\Output_out.log -S ServerA -T
```

To import the data back into a database using `BCP` you should define a batch size, such as `-b 5000` (commit transactions ever 5000 rows) so as to avoid filling up the transaction log.

You may also need to schedule the log backups more frequently during the massive import that you describe. Or you can switch to `SIMPLE` mode during the insert to the database.

**Copy from File Storage to Database**

```
bcp WorlWideImporters.Warehouse.StockItemTransactions_bcp IN D:\BCP\StockItemTransactions_native.bcp -b 5000 -h "TABLOCK" -m 1 -n -e D:\BCP\Error_in.log -o D:\BCP\Output_in.log -S ServerA -T
```

These are reliable tools, but not the fanciest. For importing data using [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) which is, in my experience, runs faster that `BCP` and it also has a parameter for controlling batch size.

You should reference [The BCP Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) and [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) if your needs are more complex than the simple examples I have used.

**However**, please notice this post with several answers: [Freeing Unused Space SQL Server Table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52317/freeing-unused-space-sql-server-table/52583#52583)

Note that Kin included the options mentioned is `BCP` and `BULK INSERT`, but there are other good options is the posts noted above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will definitely go faster without indexes. The indexes will be fragmented and need to be rebuilt anyway.  Disable the non-clustered indexes and then rebuild them.  Leave the cluster index live.

Also disable (nocheck) the FK.  FK checking is a lot of processing.  Then turn it back on (check) after the large insert.

Insert in the order of the PK.

This assumes the PK is the clustered index:

```
-- drop / disable non-clusted index and FK  
select 1 
while (@@rowcount > 0)
begin 
   insert into dest (col1, col2, ...)
   select top (100000) col1, col2, ... 
   from src 
   left join dest 
   on src.PK = dest pk 
   where dest.pk is null 
   order by src.PK
end
-- rebuild / enable index and FK
```